# PrimeFaces DataExporter for big data

Tags: excel, jsf, primefaces, bigdata, primefaces-dataexporter

I have 65000 data for getting from DB into excel.But PF DataExporter component is not writing big data into the excel.What can I use for this process?Is there a library for this process?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Timeout when exporting large dataset as XLSX using p:dataExporter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71162591/timeout-when-exporting-large-dataset-as-xlsx-using-pdataexporter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

1. Apache POI [Some examples - Quick guide](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html) very easy to use and excellent simple examples
2. Jasper reports [Just link](https://www.jaspersoft.com/reporting) - needs some time to figure it out

If you need just one excel export, use Apache POI.

If you have a lot of reports, i would recommend you to use Jasper reports because you can have option to export it to PDF, Excel, Word and other formats.

Good luck!

Comment: For anyone who wants to use just Primefaces and still adopt @jNick's first option, it is now possible to use POI streaming API with primefaces DataExporter. Exporter with option _xlsxstream_ selects this option.

`<p:dataExporter type="xlsxstream" target="my-table" fileName="my-file" />`