# Export excel with more than 256 columns with primefaces

Tags: java, excel, jsf, primefaces, apache-poi

I'm using a `primefaces` component called `dataExporter` to export data into an xls file. My problem is that I cannot have more than 256 columns in the exported excel because I get this error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid column index (256).  Allowable column range for BIFF8 is (0..255) or ('A'..'IV')
```

I investigated a bit, and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2326668/how-to-get-more-than-255-columns-in-an-excel-sheet-using-apache-poi-3-6) - so it seems my error comes from the fact that the dataExporter might use `org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel` instead of the newer `org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel`. Can I tell this `primefaces` component to use a different implementation? Or maybe I can use a different `primefaces` component? Any idea?

Comment: *so it seems my error comes from the fact that the dataExporter might use org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel instead of the newer org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel* - Correct, HSSF exports XLS, which supports a maximum of 256 columns. Did you check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22344707/primefaces-dataexporter-for-big-data)? Have a look at both the accepted answer and its comment

Comment: Correct you want to use XLSX and not old XLS to have more than 65000 cells.  It has been in PF since 6.0 fixed with this ticket: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1192

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution for my problem was indeed as suggested by @BackSlash and @Melloware in their comments

1. Upgrade my version of `primefaces` to 6.0
2. Use the `xlsxstream` type for the Exporter

   `<p:dataExporter type="xlsxstream" target="my-table" fileName="my-file" />`

Later Edit: the `xlsx` type might have been a good choice also, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741023/primefaces-dataexporter-xlsx-and-xlsxstream) for a comparison between `xlsx` and `xlsxstream`

Comment: They stated it is fixed since 6.0, not to upgrade to 6.0. So you sort of not made the best choice... Upgrade to 6.2...

Comment: You're right @Kukeltje , this is not the best choice. To keep a long story short, my current project was working with a very old version of primefaces and even the upgrade to 6.0 caused some other things to behave improperly. I will upgrade to 6.2 asap

Comment: @AndreiRS you should also mark this as the "Accepted" answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer

Comment: @Melloware I will do this asap, but according to your link "You must wait 48 hours to accept your own answer"

Comment: Understood I forgot about the 48 hour rule!