# PrimeFaces ExternalContext responsewriter concrete type

Tags: primefaces, export-to-csv

I'm looking at a csv export from a java app using JBoss and PrimeFaces.  The export is a straight call from the datatable on the web page to the PrimeFaces DataExporter and CSVExporter implementation.  I can follow it all through reasonably enough but it begins by getting the writer type from the external context of the PrimeFaces context

```
public void export(FacesContext context,...    
    ExternalContext externalContext = context.getExternalContext();
    configureResponse(externalContext, filename, encodingType);
    Writer writer = externalContext.getResponseOutputWriter();

    ...
    else {
        exportAll(context, table, writer);
    }
    ...             
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
}
```

I was wondering how I can find the concrete class of the writer ?

My end game in this is just to understand whether the export is all held in Heap Memory until the export is finished, which I suspect it is or whether there is some background process  which might be letting it go ?

So I'm assuming the flush at the end means that the file is not written until the end but I was just interested by the fact it is doing a line by line call to a cast to PrintWriter

```
protected void exportAll(FacesContext context, DataTable table, Object document) {
        for(int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; rowIndex++) {
            exportRow(table, document, rowIndex);
        }

    }
}

protected void exportRow(DataTable table, Object document, int rowIndex) {
    table.setRowIndex(rowIndex);
    ...
    exportCells(table, document); 
    ...
}

@Override
protected void exportCells(DataTable table, Object document) {
    PrintWriter writer = (PrintWriter) document;

    for (UIColumn col : table.getColumns()) {
            'write cell (no flush)           }
    }
}
```

There are many reports of people having issues with Excel but none with csv.  Is this just because the csv process is so much less resource hungry or because I'm misreading it and actually the memory is flushed between each line write ?

Comment: Why don't you set a breakpoint and run in debug? According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getResponseOutputWriter--) if used on a servlet engine (99,99999% of the time) it must return  [`ServletResponse.getWriter()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletResponse.html#getWriter--) and please add references to 'here are many reports of people having issues with Excel but none with csv. ' And yes, csv is less hungry, but for excel you can use 'streaming' so it totally depends on how the excel is generated

Comment: I answered this here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51741023/primefaces-dataexporter-xlsx-and-xlsxstream    Please upvote if it fixes your issue.